# Why does Foundation Magellan not work when following original demo?

Tags: zurb-foundation, magellan

What am I missing to make Foundation's Magellan work?

This is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MI5Studio/pen/MBVmNJ) that is not working, but I copied the same HTML and CSS from this original [Foundations Codepen](https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/gWKLqV).

I have added:

```
jquery.js
foundation.js
foundation.magellan.js
foundation.core.js
foundation.smoothScroll.js
```

But can't make it work, is something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of things...
What they don't tell you is you much have the init within a document ready

```
$(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

And the active class is

```
.is-active
```

Once you update those 2 things... your magellan will work.